# SQL Relational Ordering Based on User Ranking

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting

I am using Oracle 11g.  The rankings are not static.  They change based on how a user ranks the items.

I would like to keep a live record of rankings 1-10 using both a Rank (1-10) column and the ID of the object.  So that a user can continually rate a collection of objects and the rankings stay correct.  I've found decent a decent workaround below but there are problems with gaps:

```
// REMOVAL
UPDATE ... SET orderingID=NULL WHERE orderingID=removedID
UPDATE ... SET orderingID=orderingID-1 WHERE orderingID > removedID
// INSERTION
UPDATE ... SET orderingID=orderingID+1 WHERE orderingID > insertionID
UPDATE ... SET orderID=insertionID WHERE ID=addedID
```

If I have a table as such:

```
RANK | OBJECT

1    | AA

6    | BB
```

Using the above alogithm I ran into problems with gaps in the number.  For example, if I insert a 2 i get:

```
RANK | OBJECT

1    | AA

2    | DD

7    | BB
```

The 6 becomes a 7 when it should stay at 6.  Is there a way to do this in SQL using update statements or a store procedure ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Is this ranking static? You wrote that your ranking is 1-10. If that is so, how can you have gaps?